# Get text from textarea and append it to a hidden input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a really hard time with this. I have a template that uses a bootstrap wysiwyg and has this structure (which is added dynamically when loading the template):

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <div class="summernote" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="note-editor">
    <div class="note-dropzone">//content</div>
    <div class="note-dialog">//content</div>
    <div class="note-handle">//content</div>
    <div class="note-popover">//content</div>
    <div class="note-toolbar btn-toolbar">//content</div>
    <textarea class="note-codable"></textarea>
    <div class="note-editable" contenteditable="true">  
       <p></p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I have noticed that when inspecting the code, what I write inside the editor is being added to the p tag.

my question is, how do I get to "catch" what the user writes on the wysiwyg textarea and receive it when sending through $_POST in php?

So far, my approach is:

- get the p and add an id
- add to the p a blur function so when user stops writing and clicks outside, content can be copied into a hidden input

  ```
  window.onload = function(){
   var paragraph = $('.note-editable').find('div').find('p:first');
   paragraph.id = 'pr';

   $("#pr").blur(function(){
     alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
   });
  }
  ```

of course I'm not having success with this and my head is a little bit burned right now. Any help appreciated.

Comment: There's no need in adding id, you can use just the `paragraph` itself: `paragraph.blur(...)`. Try it.
Also, please pay attention on the `paragraph` selector - looks like `find('div')` is an extra operation - i see `p` in your code right inside the `div.note-editable`.

Comment: Are you saying you want to save it automatically without user input  (i.e. button press)?

Comment: @JustinPowell no, I want the text that is written in the wysiwyg editor (which happens to be written inside <p>) to appear in my $_POST variable when submitting entire form

Comment: Is requirement to read `textarea` or `contentEditable` element ?

Comment: @guest271314 no, when inspecting the code the text that I write inside the editor ...is being written inside the <p> tag which has no id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the built in method for summernote to get the code, then use jQuery to convert it to text.

```
var html = $('.summernote').code();
$('#hiddenField').val($(html).text());
```

Comment: I'm receiving this when inspecting: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).code is not a function :(

Comment: Oops, I copied example usage from an old version. See docs [here](http://summernote.org/#/getting-started#basic-api)

Comment: Perhaps the template uses a modified or outdated version of summernote.

Comment: I put your code inside a window.onload() and it's working. The only thing is that it not only gets the text that I enter to the editor but also the p tag....how do I remove it?

Comment: You could try `$(html).text()` if you're using jquery.

Comment: thank u, then I understood that it was ok that the p tag is being send :P

Answer (score 0):

Try using `input` event , `this.textContent` within handler to retrieve text within `.note-editable` element

```js
$(".note-editable").on("input", function(e) {
  console.log(this.textContent)
})
```

```css
.note-editable {
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <div class="summernote" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="note-editor">
    <div class="note-dropzone">//content</div>
    <div class="note-dialog">//content</div>
    <div class="note-handle">//content</div>
    <div class="note-popover">//content</div>
    <div class="note-toolbar btn-toolbar">//content</div>
    <textarea class="note-codable"></textarea>
    <div class="note-editable" contentEditable="true">  
       <p></p>
    </div>  
</div>
```